# Can static analysis of JavaScript be done?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, static-analysis

Is it possible to statistically analyze JavaScript to find obfuscated JavaScript? Any algorithms or equations with coefficients that can find obfuscated JavaScript?

Comment: What is your definition of "obfuscated Javascript"?  You'd have to define a spec for exactly what qualifies and what doesn't qualify as obfuscated before one could discuss making a detector for that.

Comment: Is it possible? You bet. But as @jfriend00 says, you need to define what obfuscated means in your environment.

Comment: In my view "statistically analyze" and static analysis are to entirely distinct methods. Please pick one or the other as answering both could result in a muddle.